# Installing files in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cuda

I need to download the NVIDIA CUDA tool kit. I am running on Ubuntu server, I don't know which one to download. I checked the ubuntu version, below is the output.

```
root@ubuserver3:/home/admin# uname -m && cat /etc/*release
i686
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="12.04.4 LTS, Precise Pangolin"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu precise (12.04.4 LTS)"
VERSION_ID="12.04"
```

The download link is this - https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads

Which one should I download? There are 2 files `.run` and `.deb` under 32 bit of Ubuntu 12.04. I have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

They are both work, but there is a little difference.

For the **deb** package, you can use

```
$ sudo dpkg -i cuda_deb_file.deb
```

the **.run** package, just

```
$ chmod +x cuda_run_file.run
$ ./cuda_run_file.run
```

The first one install the file to **/usr/bin/ /usr/include/ /usr/lib/**, but
the second one need you specify the path before installation.

Comment: @GloryOfSuccess It's OK.

Comment: If you are using 32bit Ubuntu 12.04, make sure you use the Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit installer (.run) file or package (.deb) file.  For example the run file is [this one](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/5_5/rel/installers/cuda_5.5.22_linux_32.run).  There are instructions for both methods (package installation or runfile installation) [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-linux/index.html).